# Zip replayable RxJS observables

Tags: javascript, rxjs, observable, rxjs5

I would like to combine several replayable incomplete observables that hold the last value (`BehaviorSubject` in this case) in a similar way like `zip` does, but to make the resulting observable emit a value when any source observables emits.

Here's [a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/36dkga2L/):

```
const foo$ = new Rx.BehaviorSubject('foo');
const bar$ = new Rx.BehaviorSubject('bar');

setTimeout(() => foo$.next('foo 1'), 1000)
setTimeout(() => bar$.next('bar 1'), 2000)

const foobar$ = Rx.Observable.zip(foo$, bar$);

foobar$.subscribe(([foo, bar]) => console.log({ foo, bar }));
```

Due to how `zip` operator works, the code above will output:

> {foo: "foo", bar: "bar"}
>
> {foo: "foo 1", bar: "bar 1"}

While I would like it to be

> {foo: "foo", bar: "bar"}
>
> {foo: "foo 1", bar: "bar"}
>
> {foo: "foo 1", bar: "bar 1"}

How can this be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [`combineLatest()`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#static-method-combineLatest) operator:

```
const foobar$ = Rx.Observable.combineLatest(foo$, bar$);
```

Your updated demo: https://jsfiddle.net/d1wo1usx/

Comment: Great, thanks. My bad, for some reason I thought that combineLatest works only on completed observables and had no chance to try if it's true.